Incorrect result using Dense Vector Search Query result in sorting
I am using dense vector search in solr for querying.
I want to use this score for sorting in the below mentioned sort function -
sort function: x*score+(1-x)*somefield

where x is some value assigned while querying.
dense vector search query: {!knn f=vector topK=10}[...]

I am on solr 9.1 , so I am not able to use vectorSimilarity function as well.
Is there a way to achieve what I want.
Tried these methods:-

Using scroe directly but Solr doesn't understand score as a field in any function.

If I take  the below mentioned approach then for a few docs $q returns 0 scroe. But for most of the documents the $q value matches the actual score.


sort function: x*$q+(1-x)*somefield

sort function: x*query($q)+(1-x)*somefield

I want the dense vector search to run in a way that uses the above sort function for selection of docs. But there is a workaround for this that I can mention topK=a very large number  , which is equal to the filtered docs count. And then apply sort function.
Hence I am focussing more on the other part , but if someone can suggest any other way to actually implement the complete solution, it would also help
